# Subscription and email issues

Tags: magento2, newsletter, order-email

I am having issues with subscriptions and site sending emails out.

I am pretty sure they are being caused by the same thing but I can't figure out what. Whenever a user tries to subscribe they get this message:

> Something went wrong with the subscription.

Mandrill is not install.

Comment: I think this is Magento bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4325

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: @Sejal Shah magento2.1.7